# jquery select link by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i can reference link with specific id with following code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a#example_link_id").click(function(event){
         var url = $(this).attr("href");
          get_uid(url);
         //event.preventDefault();

       });
  });
```

is it possible to use `$("a#example_link_id")` this by link name

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your selector(s) can include specific attributes as well. For example:

```
$("a[name='foo']");
```

Which would select

```
<a href="foo.html" name="foo">Foo</a>
```

For more information, http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

you might be looking for this:

```
var $link = $("a[name=some_name]");
```

where some_name is the value of the `name` attribute of the link